# Window Location Animation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation

I'm trying to animate my window's location.

**SCENARIO**:
I have a window, and when i click on my button, I want the window to move smoothly 100px from it's current location.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
Private Sub minimize_button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles minimize_button.Click

    Dim windowsize as integer = window1.top
    windowsize = windowsize - 100

End Sub
```

But with **XAML** animation. I have no idea how to make this animation in this type of scenario.

---

*Any answer is appreciated, Sincerely VenoMDee.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you're going to be able to do this with a XAML animation, but you could still achieve this effect through either a DispatcherTimer or a Storyboard.

With every tick (time-based frame) you can reset the position of the window in code.  Just fire the ticks of the timer to reproduce about 40 frames per second (every 150 milliseconds).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bit of a simpler solution:

if your trying to make you animation smooth, you need a Timer, but for every timer1.tick you need to decrease the interval unless it's > screen height. This will make it go faster the further it currently is. I've worked with this method before and the animation is really nice.

```
Timer1.Interval -= 1
Me.top = Me.Top * 1.05
If Me.Top > My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height Then
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Hope this helped!